# Changing domain DNS from godaddy to amazon Route 53 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I have this problem for about 3 days now. it seems that after changing the  DNS of (tareksadek.com) from godaddy to amazon's something is stopping the process although the amazon link works fine (http://tareksadek.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/) also did testing on (http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/?domain=tareksadek.com)

anyone got a clue on what could be preventing the DNS change?

Thanks

Comment: did you try contacting godaddy support?

Comment: Your nameservers are changed to AWS: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/tareksadek.com, but there is no `A` record for `tareksadek.com`

Comment: Any idea how i can create that A record?

Comment: @DusanBajic i have followed this example and there is no mention of A record separate creation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-switch-to-route53-as-dnsprovider

Comment: In 3.2, you create `ALIAS` records (I mentiond `A` which is usually done, but since you are hosting the site in S3 bucket, you need `ALIAS`)

Comment: @DusanBajic this is how my record set is set up [http://tareksadek.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/1.jpg]

Comment: You did well for `www.tareksadek.com`, but you need to do the same for `tareksadek.com` (leave the name blank)

Comment: Thanks a lot @DusanBajic it worked